# How convert name section (on one row) in rows of new column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I need tranform this dataframe, moving the section row to a rows, like example. I have a "section name" betwen rows, and i prefer have a column with the "section name"  in each celd, using this variable that now is in as row.

```
              F1   F2  F3          
Section name            
activity_a          
activity_b     1    2   
activity_c          3
activity_d     1    3   
activity_e          
activity_f          3
activity_g     3    
activity_h     3        
activity_i          
Section name            
activity_j     2        
activity_k     1    
activity_l     1    3   
activity_m     3        2
activity_n     3        2
activity_o     2
```

to this

```
               F1   F2  F3  section         
activity_a                  Section name_1
activity_b     1    2       Section name_1
activity_c          3       Section name_1
activity_d     1    3       Section name_1
activity_e                  Section name_1
activity_f          3       Section name_1
activity_g     3            Section name_1
activity_h     3            Section name_1
activity_i                  Section name_2
activity_j     2            Section name_2
activity_k     1            Section name_2
activity_l     1    3       Section name_2
activity_m     3        2   Section name_2
activity_n     3        2   Section name_2
activity_o     2            Section name_2
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
df$section <- paste0('Section name_', cumsum(rownames(df) == 'Section name'))
```